# How can I see the text of my deleted questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I would like to see the text of my deleted questions, but I can't figure out how to access them.

Can somebody please post the text of my deleted questions here?

Answer (score 3):

Questions that get deleted are those that are deemed obsolete, utterly useless, or completely unsalvageable. In general, they are either unabashedly spam, or they are questions that were closed with feedback prompting/encouraging the asker to reformulate their question in accordance with our guidelines, but where none of those reformulation attempts took place. The thought goes something like: if you have stopped caring about your question, well then so have we.

The point of deleting questions at all is to keep down the number of [broken windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory) on the site. We want the home page to look nice and inviting to prospective answerers, and also to serve as a representative snapshot of the types of questions that we invite/encourage. If there a bunch of bad questions listed there that are clearly off-topic or otherwise inappropriate for our site, then we leave new (and returning) users with a bad impression. And that's the *worst* thing that we could possibly do, especially on a site that's still in "beta".

And of course, under certain conditions, users can delete their *own* questions. The complication of this is that it's basically "un-revertable". Even though you can always undelete content that has not been deleted by a moderator, you can't *see* your deleted questions in your profile in order to be able to undelete them. This has been an issue for users on other Stack Exchange sites, particularly in cases where they've inadvertently deleted one of their own questions and then are unable to find a link to it to be able to undelete it. As a result, some people [have proposed that deleted questions/answers always be shown to their owner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted). However, this proposal was declined by the people who run the Stack Exchange network, so it's unlikely to be implemented. You can show your support by upvoting the question (proposal), or even leaving an answer justifying your rationale, but keep in mind that it [has already been considered and rejected for what the team presumably thinks are good reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53297/153008).

So hopefully that gives you some conceptual background on why questions might be deleted, and why you can't find them to undelete yourself.

In general, I wouldn't be very inclined to fulfill requests like this, but it doesn't look like you're one of the users who have posted spam or other obviously unacceptable content to the site, so I'll give you the benefit of the doubt. Here are the links to your questions that have been deleted; you should be able to view them (even though they've been deleted) because you are the owner:

- [Does QI prohibit extraterrestrial life?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/does-qi-prohibit-extraterrestrial-life)
- [Why perception of positive smell is so close between distant species (are there objective criteria of positive smell?)](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1364/why-perception-of-positive-smell-is-so-close-between-distant-species-are-there)
- [What is the maximum possible pain in the universe?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/what-is-the-maximum-possible-pain-in-the-universe)
- [Limit of ultimate hedonist society](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/limit-of-ultimate-hedonist-society)

If you *can't* see them for whatever reason, ping me back here and I'll consider pasting the text inline in my answer here.

---

> ### Does QI prohibit extraterrestrial life?
>
> There is a known thought experiment, connected to quantum immortality:
> a duel between physicist and a philosopher.
>
> Each turn physicist and philosopher fire at each other with a pistol.
> The quantum immortality predicts that each of the participants will
> find themselves alive and the opponent dead after a number of shots.
>
> We can modify the experiment in the following ways:
>
> 1. They do not fire at each other, but it is lightning that shots them. The outcome should not change.
> 2. There are not two but more participants.
> 3. They are located at separate islands in the ocean.
>
> It seems that even if there are hundreds of participants, each of them
> will eventually find all others killed by lightning. If he could not
> observe other isles directly, after he discovers and explores other
> isles, he will find them uninhabitable.
>
> Now pretend that the participants actually live on separate planets,
> and in each million years there happens disaster that kills all
> inhabitants on 1% of all planets. It seems that after years the
> physicist that lives on one of the planets should discover that all
> other planets are uninhabitable. Even more: there is even no chance
> that organic matter on each other planet could actually evolve into
> anything resembling actual life.
>
> That said the physicist will find out that there is no other
> inhabitable planet in the Uinverse. On the other hand, this does not
> mean that extraterrestrial life does not exist. It actually cannot not
> to exist. But it exists in parallel universes (in terms of MWI) and
> thus unobservable. Both physicist on planet A and philosopher on
> planet B exist, but will never meet in the same universe.
>
> Thus, QI it seems predicts one concrete observable consequence that
> extraterrestrial life can be never detected.
>
> What is your opinion?
>
> [metaphysics](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metaphysics) [cosmology](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmology) [quantum-physics](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-physics)
>
> *Asked Sep 14 '11 at 23:50*

---

> ### Why perception of positive smell is so close between distant species (are there objective criteria of positive smell?)
>
> It is known that the smell of flowers is generally regarded as
> positive by people.
>
> On the other hand it is known that the flowers use the smell to
> attract insects which help the flowers in sexual reproduction.
>
> Attracting mammals does not benefit survival of neither flowers nor
> mammals.
>
> Nonetheless the smell of flowers is perceived positive at least by
> humans. Does it mean there is an objective criteria of positive smell
> which are independent of other circumstances?
>
> [metaphysics](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metaphysics)
>
> *Asked Sep 25 '11 at 20:14*

---

> ### What is the maximum possible pain in the universe?
>
> Suppose it is possible to biologically modify human's brain in every
> fashion, including increasing its dimensions, mass, and any other
> feature.
>
> Let's we can concede any other abilities such as ability to calculate
> numbers and memorize in favor of the ability to feel pain.
>
> What structure should have a brain designed specially to experience
> the greatest pain possible for given mass?
>
> Is there a maximum limit to pain possible for any mass whatsoever?
>
> Also please consider an inverse question about maximum possible
> pleasure.
>
> [metaphysics](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metaphysics)
>
> *Asked Sep 25 '11 at 7:03*

---

> ### Limit of ultimate hedonist society
>
> Consider an utopic hedonist society where maximum of pleasure is
> considered the purpose of life. All kinds of drugs are allowed and the
> science works on development of even stronger drugs that can maximize
> pleasure.
>
> But some people believe that they can maximize their received pleasure
> even more not by using drugs but by modification of their brains, say,
> to experience pleasure even without drugs or to amplify the effect of
> existing drugs.
>
> What limit will reach their scientific quest for modification of their
> brains for ability to feel greater pleasure (considering that all
> kinds of modifications are allowed - not only those based on
> neuroscience)?
>
> For example, will the average mass of their brains increase in such
> pursuit or will they fuse their minds to increase pleasure?
>
> [metaphysics](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metaphysics)
>
> *Asked Sep 25 '11 at 19:33*

Comment: Thanks! But I unfortunately cannot see them...

Comment: @anixx: updated

Comment: @ Cody Gray Thank you!